# Ignoring only one parameter in a Visual Basic .net unit test's stub?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, stub

Trying to debug the problem that spawned [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678973/why-might-a-function-stub-not-get-called-in-spite-of-all-its-arguments-matching) gave me the following thought:

**Q:** is there a way to tell the stub to ignore *only some* parameters but not the others? (in opposition to ignoring all parameters with `IgnoreArguments`)

Comment: What framework are you using to create the stub? And can you clarify what you mean by "ignoring only some parameters"? (Are you wanting the stub to do something when it gets certain parameters?)

Comment: I'm using VS2012 default testing framework.

Comment: And I meant that in a particular scenario I have two calls to a method that differ in one or two parameters only and I want both to trigger the same stub (while there might be others that differ in other ways and have their own matching stubs).

Comment: The testing framework isn't the same as the mocking framework, which would be responsible for generating test doubles like stubs, etc. (The testing framework doesn't have this capability by itself.) The syntax looks like Rhino Mocks; can you confirm?

Comment: Confirmed, it's Rhino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for ignoring a parameter in VB.net is `Arg(Of T).Is.Anything`.

For example if I had:

```
myObj.Stub(Function(x) x.MyMethod(string1, string2)).Return(myReturn)
```

And I wish to ignore only string1, I could just write:

```
myObj.Stub(Function(x) x.MyMethod(Arg(Of String).Is.Anything, Arg(Of String).Is.Equal(string2))).Return(myReturn)
```

Note that in order to ignore one or more parameters this way ALL of them must be written in that notation, even the ones that you want to have a specific value (with the `.Is.Equal(...)` notation).

Answer found thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678973/why-might-a-function-stub-not-get-called-in-spite-of-all-its-arguments-matching#comment36380268_23679668)